# SQLite query execution crashes Android App

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I am populating a listview from SQLite database, and the app crashes when I click on an item. I have done enough research using "query" and "rawquery". Also successfully executed rawquery statement in SQLite Database Browser, but still the same statement doesn't work in my code.

Below is the code of my listview onitemclicklistener:

```
//  Bookmark ListView Listener
    bookmarkListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent1, View view1, int position1,
                long id1) {
            String selectedBookmarkItem = ((TextView)view1).getText().toString();

            dbAdapter.read();

            Map<String, Object> bookmarkKV = dbAdapter.getSingleBookmark(selectedBookmarkItem);
            String bookmarkedURL = (String) bookmarkKV.get(dbAdapter.BOOKMARK_ADDRESS);

            dbAdapter.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), bookmarkedURL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
```

Method getSingleBookmark code:

```
//  Fetch Single Bookmark
public Map<String, Object> getSingleBookmark(String bookmarkName1) throws SQLException{
    Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Cursor cursor1 = db.query(true, BOOKMARKS_TABLE, new String[] {BOOKMARK_ADDRESS},
            BOOKMARK_NAME + "=" + bookmarkName1, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor1 != null){
        cursor1.moveToFirst();
    }

    String bookmarkAddress = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(BOOKMARK_ADDRESS));
    map1.put(BOOKMARK_ADDRESS, bookmarkAddress);
    //String bookmarkName = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(BOOKMARK_NAME));
    //map1.put(BOOKMARK_NAME, bookmarkName);

    return map1;
}
```

LogCat entry:

```
09-30 03:43:12.791: E/AndroidRuntime(29008): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 03:43:12.791: E/AndroidRuntime(29008): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:     
no such column: gmail (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT bookmarkaddress 
FROM bookmarkstable WHERE bookmarkname=gmail
```

When I click on "gmail" item in listview, the app crashes saying "Unfortunately, App has stopped".

But the database table has the row with "gmail" entry:

[image]

Comment: Looking at that query it looks like gmail should have single quotes around it e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT bookmarkaddress 
FROM bookmarkstable WHERE bookmarkname='gmail'`

Comment: Whenever something crashes, an exception is generated. You can write that data to a log file and see :)

Comment: can you post your onCreate method code of your database class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in the error message:

```
no such column: gmail
```

you see the query that it's trying to run includes

```
WHERE bookmarkname=gmail
```

Your query needs to be modified to indicate that it's a string - in your cursor, change:

```
BOOKMARK_NAME + "=" + bookmarkName1
```

for:

```
BOOKMARK_NAME + "='" + bookmarkName1 + "'"
```

This will then put the value of "bookmarkName1" in single quote marks.

Selvin's edit: or even better, use parameters(using them will avoid future problems with strings containing `'`):

```
db.query(true, BOOKMARKS_TABLE, new String[] {BOOKMARK_ADDRESS},
                BOOKMARK_NAME + "=?", 
                new String[] { bookmarkName1 }, 
null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: In short, it has to be `WHERE bookmarkname='gmail'`. All Strings in SQL have to be enclosed in single quotes :)

Comment: No problem, Selvin's edit is **much** cleaner, but judging from the question, I'd assume you need some experience with the format of SQL commands, so doing it the way I posted should be easier for you to follow along with.

Answer (score 0):

Always when using raw query you must surround strings with quote and also escape quotas in your string (replace `'` with `\'`).

The best way is to use selection and selection arguments, so it is done for you:

```
mContext.getContentResolver().query(Model.CONTENT_URI, null, SELECTION,
                    new String[] { ARGUMENT }, null);
```

Where `SELCTION` contains ? signs, eg: `name=?`